# make target, unmake target?

Tags: makefile, rollback

Since make knows all dependencies to make a target, it knows (almost) all intermediate artefacts.  Is there a make version that can 'rollback', or 'unmake' a target?

(I know it removes targets created by implicit rules)

Answer (score 0):

Most Makefiles provide the `clean` target, which removes all generated files. Additionally, `autoconf`-`automake` systems offer `distclean`, which also removes the files generated by `configure`.

These are no automatic targets, however; the makefile generation system gives a list of generated files to `make`. In general, `make` doesn't keep track which files it generated, so it can't distinguish between genuine source files (which are dependencies) and intermediate files (which are also dependencies). Even the leaf nodes of the dependency graph can't be used for distinguishment, because stamp files often have no dependencies as well.